# An error when removing a file using remove() function

Tags: c++

I have problem with remove() function

First, look at the example and you will see the problem

```
cout << "Please enter the phone number to remove" << endl << "Phone number: ";
string rphNumber;
cin >> rphNumber;
ifstream ifile("db/" + rphNumber + ".txt");
if(ifile)
  remove(("db/" + rphNumber + ".txt").c_str()); // the problem here
else
  cout << "failure" << endl;
```

The problem in this line (the file path), always the function return -1 Although the file exists

```
remove(("db/" + rphNumber + ".txt").c_str());
```

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: unfortunately, no error message

Comment: @LionKing which plattform are you using?

Comment: @FailedDev:: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem *may* be that you still have `ifile` open at the point where you try to remove it.  Some operating systems don't let you delete a file that's open.  Another possibility is that the string `rphNumber` might have a newline at the end which you need to strip off before assembling the filename.  (I don't remember if `cin` does that or not.)

Your problem definitely *is* that you are trying to find out if a filesystem operation will work.  You can't do that.  In between when you make the test and when you actually try to do the operation, another process may change things so that the operation won't work, even though your test said it will.  Also, being able to *open* a file is not the same as being able to *delete* a file; there are probably lots of files on your hard drive that you can open but not delete (such as `/dev/null`).

You have to just *do* the filesystem operation.  It will tell you if it worked or not, with its return value.  Then, when it doesn't work, you look at `errno` to find out why.  The C utility function `strerror` (include `<cstring>`) will convert an `errno` value to a human-readable error message.

Putting it together, here's the correct way to write your program:

```
cout << "Please enter the phone number to remove.\nPhone number: ";
string rphNumber;
cin >> rphNumber;
string fname("db/" + rphNumber + ".txt");

if (remove(fname.c_str()))
    cout << "Failed to delete '" << fname << "': " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
else
    cout << '\'' << fname << "' successfully deleted.\n";
```

Incidentally, never use `endl`; if `'\n'` doesn't work, it means your streambufs are not configured correctly.

Comment: The Error message is :: failed to delete c://fileName.txt : permission denied

Comment: That can't be right, since the program is trying to delete a file in a directory named 'db'.  What did it *really* say?

Answer (score 1):

If `remove` is failing, it will set `errno` as well as returning `-1`. I'm not entirely *how* you're sure it's failing since you don't actually store the return value in a variable.

But, assuming it *is* returning -1, print `errno` out so you can tell what the actual error is, something like:

```
int rc = remove(("db/" + rphNumber + ".txt").c_str());
if (rc < 0)
    perror ("could not remove file");
```

Comment: paxdiablo:: unfortunately, no error message appears, but the function return -1

Comment: I don't recommend using `perror` because it makes you choose between reporting the *operation* that failed and reporting the *name of the file* that couldn't be operated on, when you really should report both.

Comment: @Zack, I'm not proposing this as a production fix, just for temp debug code to find out the problem. In any case, you could put both those items into a string passed to `perror`.

Comment: I guess that's not remotely as annoying to do in C++ as it is in C, huh.  Well, except for the risk that under-the-hood memory allocation will clobber `errno`.  Which is maybe not worth worrying about.  As you say, this is temporary debug code.

Comment: The Error message is :: failed to delete c://fileName.txt : permission denied